# Safety of database connection pools - releasing a connection back to the pool with bad settings

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, node-mysql

How safe is connection pooling with regard to connection settings? When a connection is released back to the pool, does the pool issue some sort of reset command to restore the connection to a known state, or is the connection just naively returned to the pool?

This is something that always bothers me when writing code that uses `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`. If I forget/fail to call `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` before releasing the connection back to the pool, does the next process end up with an unsafe connection with foreign key checks disabled?

Since this may be specific to the pooling software, I'm mainly asking about node-mysql and JDBC. I looked at the code for node-mysql and couldn't see anything that resets the connection. I have no idea about JDBC.

Comment: Are you interested in general behaviour expected by JDBC, or the specific behaviour of MySQL Connector/J?

Comment: Both. I haven't even been able to find this even being discussed anywhere so far so any information at all would be helpful. Is this not being discussed because it's a non-issue because everyone is doing it right, or has nobody noticed that this could be really dangerous?

Comment: In JDBC this has historically mostly been left up to the vendor, or - by absence of such requirements - to the user themselves. Ideally, a connection would be fully reset back to its original state. Practically, this doesn't happen, or at least not completely (especially when using third-party connection pools that don't know about the specifics of the underlying database).